# Troubleshooting Webpage Access From Public IP

Tags: server, ssl-certificate, timeout

I operate a server that runs continuously throughout the day, hosting a webpage on port 8443. This webpage serves as a management interface for my Minecraft servers, which are also hosted on the same server but on port 25565.

Locally, I can access the webpage in my browser using HTTPS by entering https://192.168.1.140:8443, the correct local IP address and port. Although I receive a notice about potential data theft due to the self-signed certificate, this is expected.

However, the issue arises when attempting to access the webpage using the public IP address. I have successfully port forwarded both 8443 and 25565 on my router, and I can access the Minecraft servers with no problem by entering my public IP address and port. Strangely, the webpage fails to load. Upon the initial attempt to visit the webpage using the public IP address, I receive the "steal my information" notice. Despite clicking on "proceed anyway," the webpage doesn't load properly. Additionally, it continues to display the self-signed certificate, even though none of the webpage content is loaded.

I would appreciate any assistance with resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Did you installed the self-signed certificate on the client machine you are using to access the management webpage?

Comment: What webserver are you using?